# feed_parser gem working in production console but not on production web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the feed_parser gem in a Rails app. It works exactly as indicated in development and also works in the production console, but it won't load on the production web server.

(Note: It even works fine on our Ubuntu 12.04 test server, fails on 10.04 production server)

`uninitialized constant - Project::FeedParser`

I am running this in one of the models of our website:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.facebook_feed
    url = "http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=236004913152511&format=rss20"
    posts = Project.parse_feed(url)
    return posts
  end

  def self.blogspot_feed
    url = "http://fundinggarage.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss"
    posts = Project.parse_feed(url)
    return posts
  end

  private

  def self.parse_feed(feed_url)
    feed = FeedParser.new(:url => feed_url).parse
    fj = feed.as_json
    #fj[:items].first[:description]
    posts = []
    fj[:items].take(4).each do |fp|
      post = {}
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(fp[:description])
      img_srcs = doc.css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }
      post[:headline] = fp[:title]
      post[:image] = "/assets/fg_image_placehloder.png"
      post[:image] = img_srcs.first unless img_srcs.first.nil?
      post[:url] = fp[:link]
      post[:date] = fp[:published]
      posts << post
    end
    return posts
  end
end
```

In the view:

```
<% Project.blogspot_feed.each do |fb| %>
    <div class="grid_3">
      <div class="media other-post-item">
        <a href="<%= fb[:url] %>" class="thumb-left" target="_blank">
          <div class="blog-img">
            <img src="<%= fb[:image] %>" alt="<%= raw fb[:headline] %>" title="<%= raw fb[:headline] %>">
          </div>
          <span class="be-fc-orange">
            <h4 class="rs title-other-post"><%= raw fb[:headline] %></h4>
            <p class="rs fc-gray time-post pb10"><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(fb[:date])} ago" %></p>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div><!--end: . other-post-item -->
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter is looking for the `FeedParser` class to be defined, and can't find it - the error indicates it is looking in the `Project` class, as it can't find it elsewhere.

I would add the `require 'feed_parser'` to the top of the `Project` model, above the class declaration.

I am assuming this is the gem you are using:

https://rubygems.org/gems/feed_parser

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting an error: `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- feed_parser (LoadError)`

Comment: In that case it is not available at all, check out your bundle configuration perhaps? Could also be how the web server is finding gems - are you using a gemset for this?

Comment: I was using a gemset and I removed it but still the same problems. I also tried just installing the gem directly on the server.